# Why is my ethernet connection showing as both a Public and Private Network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, router, ethernet

The image below is from my "Network and Sharing Centre" on a Windows 10 installation. There is one ethernet cable connected to one network, however it shows up as two separate networks as far as I can tell. I have confirmed the default gateways and IP addresses are identical. I have connected this system to a different network with an ethernet cable and the same problem occurs.

[image: Network and Sharing Centre]

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: do you have a wifi adapter installed? try disabling it.

Comment: Do you have a USB to ethernet adapter connected? Docking station?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I do have a WiFi adapter, but unfortunately disabling it only removes the wifi connection shown in the picture above. I'm not using a USB to ethernet adapter no, just a plain ol' ethernet port.

Comment: Can you show us what you get if you click the "Change Adapter Settings" link on the left of that screen?  I suspect there may be some virtual network interface on the system that has no gateway assigned (which Windows will always mark as unidentified/public).

Comment: I think you may have been right there David, after uninstalling the Ethernet controller from device manager and reinstalling it, everything went back to normal, thanks to all for your help

Comment: Good to hear.  If it comes back, I recommend disabling the interface you removed rather than uninstalling it.  That will be a bit more persistent since uninstalling a physical device *should* just allow it to be reinstalled on the next scan/reboot.